# Extract and format a part of String in C#

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I am wondering if someone could help me with either a regex or substring options.

I have a string:

```
Line1 ("Application", "People", "people DB", "PP01", 1, X, "Y")]
```

From the above, would like to extract and display : `PP01 - People`

Comment: Are the lines always of the same format and size?

Comment: @Satya You mean to say you want alphanumeric string or just those 2 strings?

Comment: Do you mean the second and fourth item in that comma-separated list? You haven't explained well enough what you need.

Comment: @Deepak: please don't add please-help begging into other people's questions. We try to remove chat here, not add it in `:-)`.

Comment: Satya: please _always_ show your attempt prior to asking a question. Not only does it quickly clarify requirements, but it helps readers determine whether you're in the habit of making an honest effort, or just looking for free work.

Comment: @halfer: Yes, my apologies, should have posted my code along with my question. I have in the past, but slipped my mind this time, but will do next time. Appreciate the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all your lines are structured the same ..

Line1("Application", "People", "people DB", "PP01", 1, X, "Y")]
Line2("Application", "People", "people DB", "PP02", 2, X, "Y")]
Line3("Application", "People", "people DB", "PP03", 3, X, "Y")]

.. you could also make use of the string methods .Replace() and .Split():

```
string str = "\"Application\", \"People\", \"people DB\", \"PP01\", 1, X, \"Y\"";
string[] parts = str.Replace("\"", string.Empty)
                    .Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Console.Write(parts[3] + " - " + parts[1]);
```

Output would be: `PP01 - People`

Comment: Thank you. this worked. I did the str.Replace part, but had difficulty with the .Split. You recommendation. Worked. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to solve this:

```
.*?\(.*?, "(?<Group>.*?)",.*?, "(?<WhatEverPP01Is>.*?)",.*
```

Then you can match the regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(".*?\\(.*?, \"(?<Group>.*?)\",.*?, \"(?<WhatEverPP01Is>.*?)\",.*");

var match = regex.Match("YourStringToMatch");

if (match.Success)
{
    // Here you can access the group values:
    var groupValue = match.Groups["Group"].Value;
    var whateverPP01Is = match.Groups["WhatEverPP01Is"].Value;
}
```